# Getting weird Nullpointer Exception ProGuard

Tags: android

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
   at com.x.c.l.d(ProGuard:713)
   at com.x.c.e.c(ProGuard:161)
   at com.x.b.a.a(ProGuard:41)
   at com.x.b.a$1.run(ProGuard:646)
   at com.x.c.o$1.run(ProGuard:110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Can you tell when is it happening and also show the code where is it happening? this is not a complete question!

Comment: Don't know which part of code is causing it, i tried to retrace it but got nothing, getting these crashes in crashlytics.

Comment: are you sure that all you have? Could you share your mainActivity or the initial activity that is being runned? because seeing JUST at the error catelog will not help us debug!

Comment: actually I met the same problem. And only getting this crash in crash analytics system. Do you have code in you project that will dynamic load class from outside?

Comment: I decompiled my app, there is no code like com.x . I guess maybe some lib will dynamic load code or the phone of user has been hacked and our process was injected with malware code.

Comment: I have the same problem, same stack trace, can't find the source of it

Comment: It seem some of the dynamically used methods are also shrink-ed(compressed) when enabled the Proguard, so when that methods are trying to call then you are getting the null pointer exceptions, if you are using any documented third party libraries you have to keep some of class and attributes as they informed in documentation for using Proguard, for example for Crosswalk library they have given following  in FAQ `-keep class org.xwalk.core.** {
    *;
}
-keep class org.chromium.** {
    *;
}
-keepattributes **`

Answer (score 0):

I think this code was injected by a malware (Xposed etc) or your app was hacked, repackaged and published elsewhere. I receive the same crashes. If you looked into stack traces from other threads you would very likely find there an ad serving code. I did find it, unfortunately.

Comment: if somebody can find solution for this will be really good. I saw that this crash is coming suddenly from some of the previous versions of my app, which are released months ago and the problem did not appear before that, super strange