# NullPointerException in Gradle at compile 'com.x.c.l.d'

Tags: android

> buildTypes
>    {debug {proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt' proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'} release {proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'}}

Comment: Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.x.c.l.d(ProGuard:713)
       at com.x.c.e.c(ProGuard:161)
       at com.x.b.a.a(ProGuard:41)
       at com.x.b.a$1.run(ProGuard:646)
       at com.x.c.o$1.run(ProGuard:110)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: looks like a duplicate to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980484/getting-weird-nullpointer-exception-proguard